# Is it possible to have column ordering with Isotope? (jQuery library)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

I have a 2-row horizontally scrolling list with pictures, and I'd like to order elements in columns, so the second is below the first, the third is in the next column, the fourth is below, and so on...
Like this:

```
[1]  [3]  [5]  [7]  ...  ...
[2]  [4]  [6]  [8]  ...  ...
```

Is this possible? How?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are your elements gonna be static as in it won't be dynamically generated?

Comment: No, they're not static. They're dynamically generated from a database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'd want something like `masonryHorizontal` or `fitColumns`, see here:

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/layout-modes.html

Comment: Both seem to work. I had already tested those modes and they didn't work for me for whatever reason. I suppose something in my HTML has changed from that moment, so now those two layouts work as intended. Thank you!